# ¿Cómo puedo establecer una sesión en la base de datos codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy usando la nueva versión 3.x de CodeIgniter y tengo un nuevo problema, mis sesiones no funcionan y no recibe datos en mysql. quiero decir, el código en el controlador es correcto porque no hay errores, pero cuando intento imprimir una variable PHP en una vista no hay nada.

revisé mi tabla en el servidor MySQL, y nada, ahora no sé cuál es el problema. Pongo mi código de config.php. (No entiendo muchas cosas en esta nueva versión)

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database');
```

base de datos MYSQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Controller Home.php

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Interprete_registro extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            /*$this->ads = '';
            $this->ads = $this->ads_model->get_ads();*/
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailI', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[tbl_interpretes.emailI]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('contrasenaI', 'Contraseña', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('ccontrasenaI', 'Confirma contraseña', 'trim|required|matches[contrasenaI]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
                return;
            }

            $arrayI = array(

                'emailI' => $this->input->post('emailI'),
                'contrasenaI' => $this->input->post('contrasenaI'));

            $interpreteID = $this->interprete_model->add_interprete($arrayI);

            $user_data = array(
                        'username' => $this->input->post('emailI'), 
                        'is_logged_in' => 1
            ); 

            print_r($this->session->set_userdata($user_data));

            redirect(base_url('interprete/mi_cuenta'),'');
    }
}
```

View
Home_view.php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya ingresado y recibe datos en mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no recibe datos (ci_session) en mysql para informacion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene el mismo problema, ayúdame por favor

Comment: No entiendo cual es el problema, no guarda datos en la tabla ci_sessions? o que resultado deseas obtener con el código que compartes?

Comment: necesita guardar datos en la tabla ci_sessions para ajustar los datos en la sesión

Comment: debe sesión ha caducado para conectarse primero.

Answer (score 1):

Para almacenar la sesión en una base de datos, los datos de configuración deben ser los siguientes:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

donde ci_sessions en el nombre de la tabla donde quieres almacenarlos.

Intenta cambiando esas lineas de la configuración.

Mas informacion en la [ayuda oficial](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver)

Comment: ya ha cambiado , resultado: Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeignter\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeignter\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 268

Comment: El error es por que no puede abrir el fichero error_php.php revisa si existe todo ese directorio en codeigniter, esta bien escrito C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeignter\?? ahi le falta una i, quizas es C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter

Comment: Juan Pinzon podemos en chat?